# Can I update - Java - ChromeDevTools log header?

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

I've used Spring Boot with org.openqa.selenium.devtools.devTools.

When I request a connection to other servers, it write logs as this:

```
2022-07-30 18:05:53 - [CDP Connection][INFO] Matching Network.loadingFinished with Network.responseReceived
```

My code:

```
chromeDevTools.addListener(Network.requestWillBeSent(), requestWillBeSent -> {
    Headers headers = requestWillBeSent.getRequest().getHeaders();
    String nowUrl = requestWillBeSent.getRequest().getUrl();`

    if (url.contains("test.url")) {
        String url = null;
        for (String currUrl : urlList) {
            if (nowUrl.contains(currUrl)) {
                url = currUrl;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (url != null)
            // Do something
    }
});
```

I thought it writes this log when the code process `addListener`, but I want to update log header like this:

```
2022-07-30 18:05:53 - [Custom Header][INFO] Matching Network.loadingFinished with Network.responseReceived
```

I was searching for controlling it in Domains.java, Network.java, also failed. Anyone help?

Comment: This is probably the result of the logging library and its configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and kind updating my question! i've forgatten this configuration. if i ask another question, i will write better.